# I keep getting this error message when I get to the installation step when installing Spotify

Tags: java, spotify

```
download failed
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java9-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java9-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The error message you posted has nothing to do with Spotify. It has to do with a failed attempt of installing the not-recommended Oracle Java 9 (for the moment use Java 8).

Comment: the how do i install spotify? i follow the direction by spotify, get to the lastone it runs through then says that at the end making it so i cant install spotify. i have the current version of java and see no use to put java 90 on.

Comment: https://www.spotify.com/uk/download/linux/

Comment: i follow the direction by spotify, get to the lastone it runs through then says that at the end making it so i cant install spotify. i have the current version of java and see no use to put java 9

Comment: this is right about the java error.

Resolving www.oracle.com (www.oracle.com)... 23.39.16.136, 2001:428:6402:18c::2d3e, 2001:428:6402:19c::2d3e
Connecting to www.oracle.com (www.oracle.com)|23.39.16.136|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2017-05-23 13:31:18 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.

Comment: So you better retrace what you did that led to the current error and correct it before anything else. Maybe `sudo apt-get purge oracle-java9-installer` is enough...

Comment: thank you! i purged before but i dont know what happend for me to havwe to do it again. still very new to linux. thank yuo for you help today!